# Group XML elements by key

Tags: xml, xslt, key, xslt-1.0, grouping

I have this code in xml I wanted to group by the "inicial" attribute but there is no way. I leave the current xml and xsl code.

I have tried to use a key to group but there is no way to visualize grouped, sorry for my English

Related links:

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/group_xml_elements_by_key_using_xslt1.html

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1849/Grouping-XML-using-XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look at your related links, but check out [this page on Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). It does a good job of explaining grouping in XSLT 1.0.

You didn't supply your desired output as code, so my example below just adds the grouping. You may need to tweak it to get the display you want.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:key name="i" match="contacte" use="@inicial"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Contactes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="agenda.css"/>
      </head> 
      <body>
        <h1>Contactes</h1>
        <xsl:call-template name="mostrar_contactes"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="mostrar_contactes">
    <xsl:for-each select="agenda/contacte[count(.|key('i',@inicial)[1])=1]">
      <xsl:sort select="cognom1"/>

      <h4><xsl:value-of select="@inicial" /></h4>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('i',@inicial)"/>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contacte">
    <div class="contacte">
      <xsl:if test="foto=''">
        <img src="imatges/perfilneutre.jpg"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="foto!=''">
        <img src="imatges/{foto}"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <h2 class="nom"><xsl:value-of select="nom"/></h2>
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="cognom1"/></h2>
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="telefons/telmovil"/></h3>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsC

Comment: Thaks! Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

If you are limited to xslt 1, you can use the muenchian grouping method:

http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

In your case this would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="inicial" match="contacte" use="@inicial"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Contactes</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="agenda.css"/>
            </head> 
            <body>
                <h1>Contactes</h1>
                <xsl:call-template name="mostrar_contactes"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="mostrar_contactes">
        <xsl:for-each select="agenda/contacte[count(.|key('inicial', @inicial)[1]) = 1]">

            <h4><xsl:value-of select="@inicial" /></h4>

            <xsl:for-each select="key('inicial', @inicial)">
                <xsl:sort select="cognom1"/>
                <div class="contacte">
                    <xsl:if test="foto=''">
                        <img src="imatges/perfilneutre.jpg"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="foto!=''">
                        <img src="imatges/{foto}"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <h2 class="nom"><xsl:value-of select="nom"/></h2>
                    <h2><xsl:value-of select="cognom1"/></h2>
                    <h3><xsl:value-of select="telefons/telmovil"/></h3>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```